# Combining 3 different queries

Tags: mysql, ssrs-2008

I'm querying a MySQL db for a report in SSRS 2008, and I have no problem using the following to join two different queries...

```
SELECT a.arrivalDate, a.order_item_id, b.roomType
FROM 
(select order_item_id, meta_value as arrivalDate from `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'Arrival Date') as a, 
(select order_item_id, meta_value as roomType from `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'type-of-room') as b
WHERE a.order_item_id = b.order_item_id
```

...but when I try to add a third, it's taking issue with my WHERE clause, but I coulda swore I used to do it this way:

```
SELECT a.arrivalDate, a.order_item_id, b.roomType, c.retreatDate
FROM 
(select order_item_id, meta_value as arrivalDate from `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'Arrival Date') as a, 
(select order_item_id, meta_value as roomType from `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'type-of-room') as b,
(select order_item_id, meta_value as retreatDate from `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'retreat-date') as c,
WHERE a.order_item_id = b.order_item_id AND a.order_item_id = c.order_item_id
```

Any advice?

Comment: Incidentally, it's not how I'd do it - but what's with the ssrs tag?

Comment: It's for SSRS, and it's in the SQL Server Report Builder

Comment: I'm open to suggestions if you know of another way that might be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, got it! I thought this is what I tried originally, but I must've had a typo. Hopefully, my error will help others stumbling across this in the future:

```
SELECT a.arrivalDate, a.order_item_id, b.roomType, c.retreatDate
FROM 
(select order_item_id, meta_value as arrivalDate from `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'Arrival Date') as a, 
(select order_item_id, meta_value as roomType from `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'type-of-room') as b,
(select order_item_id, meta_value as retreatDate from `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'retreat-date') as c
where a.order_item_id = b.order_item_id AND b.order_item_id = c.order_item_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with either of the conventional solutions - the first is (IMO) easier to read. The second is typically faster...

Query 1

```
SELECT order_item_id
     , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'Arrival Date' THEN meta_value END) arrivalDate
     , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'type-of-room' THEN meta_value END) roomType
     , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'retreat-date' THEN meta_value END) retreatDate
  FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta 
 GROUP
    BY order_item_id
```

Query 2

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.order_item_id
              , arrival.meta_value arrivalDate
              , room.meta_value roomType
              , date.meta_value retreatDate
           FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta x
           LEFT
           JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta arrival
             ON arrival.order_item_id = x.order_item_id
            AND arrival.meta_key = 'Arrival Date' 
           LEFT
           JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta room
             ON room.order_item_id = x.order_item_id
            AND room.meta_key = 'type-of-room' 
           LEFT
           JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta date
             ON date.order_item_id = x.order_item_id;
```

Comment: Well thank you for your suggestions. I appreciate your time.